# Is there an example implementation of std::allocator_traits using custom *alloc/*free function pair?

Tags: c++

My goal is to create an std::allocator type utilizing specific allocate/free function pair (i.e LocalAlloc/LocalFree in Win32). I've been advised to subclass the std::allocator template class, but it just wraps std::allocator_traits. I want to subclass std::allocator_traits as it is smaller type, and std::allocator wraps it.

I've found [std::allocator_traits/cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits), but it doesn't have an example implementation of it by now.

Comment: "*it just wraps std::allocator_traits*" No, it does not.

Comment: Try to show some of what you have tried and why it doesn't work so that you might get more answers.

Comment: I've tried to use subclassing std::allocator, modifying allocate/deallocate functions to call the custom alloc/free function pair at first.

Comment: I've gone this path as I need to wrap LocalFree/LocalAlloc functions into std::allocator type.

Comment: Looking to this past question, I cringed a bit to be honest. Beginner mistakes has to be learnt from and to be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not "subclass" `allocator_traits` (or any C++ "traits") type. If you need to override the default traits behavior, then you create a *specialization* of the traits type. Since `allocator_traits` takes as a template parameter the allocator to use with it, this means that you are going to be creating an allocator type.

Or to put simply, creating an allocator type is not optional. It doesn't have to be (and probably shouldn't be) derived from `std::allocator`, but you have to create an allocator type in order to create your own allocator.